# Cutting part of stack trace on exceptions?

Tags: javascript, exception, stack-trace

I've a little utilility function, that call another function, if its defined

```
function ifcall(func, params) {
  if (func) params = func(params)
  return params
}

// simple use case
let err = (msg) => { throw new Error(msg) }

ifcall(err, "oops..")
```

I prefer this way instead writing the full if every time I need call a variable.

So far, so good. But this brings a little debugger annoyance:

When function called, raise an error, the stack trace starts inside the ifcall() function and not on the caller.

Here is the point: Thre is a way to manipulate the stack trace and make the error point up to the caller?

Answer (score 0):

Which debugger are you using?

Here's with NodeJS in a terminal.
[image: node screenshot]

Here's with Chrome devtools.
[image: chrome devtools screenshot]

Maybe you oversimplified your example and the code presented doesn't contain the issue you mentioned?

Sometimes, when I can't see my function in a stack trace, it's because it's an anonymous function and I can't make it out amongst the rest...

Comment: the first example I posted it done w/ Node 12 too. Have you tried running the code shown above? Or is the problem in a bigger more complex program?

Comment: I asking mainly because these functions in real use are in different files on the project, so the IDE allways show me the file containing ifcall() instead of caller.